# kendo grid editing with kendoUpload control

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Has anyone add the kendoUpload control with in the kendo grid? I would like to add it so I dont have to build an extra panel to store the controls?

> Would I add it as a template?

```
       if (!kendoGrid) {
        $("#kgridDocuments").kendoGrid({
            scrollable: false,
            toolbar: ["search", "create","save", "cancel"],

            ],
            noRecords: {
                template: "No Result Found."
            },
        });
    }

    var kendoUpload = $("#uploadMeetingDocument").data("kendoUpload");
    if (!kendoUpload) {
        $("#uploadMeetingDocument").kendoUpload();
    }
```

Uploaded code

```
 var uploadInput = '<form method="post" action="#"><div><input name="upload" type="file" /></div></form>';

        if (!kendoGrid) {
            $("#kgridDocuments").kendoGrid({
                scrollable: false,
                toolbar: ["search", "create", "save", "cancel"],
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    $("input[type='file']").kendoUpload();
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        template: "#= uploadInput #",
                        title: "File Upload"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "FileType",
                        title: "File Type"
                    }
                ],
                noRecords: {
                    template: "No Result Found."
                },
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add an upload component inside the grid. Use the column template to create the input tag and the dataBound function to initialize the kendoUpload component. Here is an example may help you.

```
<table id="grid" style="width: 100%"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var uploadInput = '<form method="post" action="#"><div><input name="upload" type="file" /></div></form>';

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: yourDataSource,
        dataBound: function(e) {
            $("input[type='file']").kendoUpload();
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                title: "Id",
                filterable: false
            },
            {
                field: "StatusText",
                title: "StatusText"
            },
            {
                title: "Upload",
                filterable: false,
                sortable: false,
                template: "#= uploadInput #"
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have it wired up with a create in the toolbar but it will not display?